# Libgdx table rows overlapping?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm new to Libgdx and just started looking at UI with tables. I have a textlabel (a font actually) and 2 image buttons. I'd like the font to be on one row and the 2 buttons below it. I've followed a tutorial but it seems the label's row is being rendered below the buttons row. Does anyone know why?

Here's my code

```
public MainScreen() {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),
                      false, spriteBatch);

    //Create the text object that says "PennyPop"
    TextLabel pennyLabel = new TextLabel();
    //Create the sfx and api button button
    ImageButton sfxButton = createSfxButton();
    ImageButton apiButton = createApiButton();


     Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

     //Create the root table
     Table rootTable = new Table();
     rootTable.setFillParent(true);
     rootTable.debug();

     //Set up rows and columns
     table = new Table();
     table.add(pennyLabel);
     table.row();
     table.add(apiButton);
     table.add(sfxButton).padLeft(10);



     rootTable.add(table);                      
     stage.addActor(rootTable);

}
```

/***ACTORS ***/

```
 public class TextLabel extends Actor {
     float textWidth;   
     float textHeight;
        private BitmapFont font;

        public TextLabel(){
            font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.fnt"),
                                  false);
            textWidth = font.getBounds("PennyPop").width;
            textHeight = font.getBounds("PennyPop").height;

            font.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        @Override
        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
             font.draw(batch, "Pennypop", (stage.getWidth()-textWidth)/2,
                                       (stage.getHeight()-textHeight)/2);
             //Also remember that an actor uses local coordinates
             // for drawing within
             //itself!
        }
 }

 public ImageButton createSfxButton(){

            ImageButton sfxButton;

            buttonsUi = new TextureAtlas("assets/buttons/buttons.pack");
            Skin buttonSkin = new Skin(buttonsUi);

            ImageButtonStyle ButtonStyle = new ImageButtonStyle();
            //Set image for not pressed  
            ButtonStyle.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("sfxButton"); 
            //Set image for pressed
            ButtonStyle.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("apiButton");  
            ButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1; 
            ButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;

            sfxButton = new ImageButton(ButtonStyle);
                sfxButton.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);

            //Initialize Sound Effect
             final Sound wavSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal(
                                     "assets/button_click.wav"));

              sfxButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
                    @Override 
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
                        wavSound.play();                       
                    }
                });


            return sfxButton;

 }

 public ImageButton createApiButton(){

        ImageButton apiButton;

        buttonsUi = new TextureAtlas("assets/buttons/buttons.pack");
        Skin buttonSkin = new Skin(buttonsUi);

        ImageButtonStyle ButtonStyle = new ImageButtonStyle(); 
        //Set image for not pressed 
        ButtonStyle.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("apiButton");  
        //Set image for pressed
        ButtonStyle.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("sfxButton");  
        ButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1; 
        ButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;

        apiButton = new ImageButton(ButtonStyle);

          apiButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){

              //Fetch the weather api and add it to the stage
                @Override 
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
                    WeatherReport weatherReport = new WeatherReport();
                }
            });


        return apiButton;

 }
```

Comment: The problem is that your TextLabel class ignores its own x and y fields in its draw method. A Table arranges its children by setting their position (relative to itself). The label should draw itself relative to its own getX() and getY(). The TextLabel class also fails to set its bounds, so the Table will have trouble reserving the correct amount of space for it. Any reason you aren't using the existing Label class?

Comment: now tend your question after reading the comment, Tenfour04, my answer was thinking you wanted to know how to show the actors, one beside the other, sorry